# How to compile OpenJDK 11 on macOS?

Tags: java, c++, compiler-errors, java-11

When I make, with:

Configuration summary:

- Debug level:    fastdebug
- HS debug level: fastdebug
- JVM variants:   server
- JVM features:   server: 'aot cds cmsgc compiler1 compiler2 dtrace epsilongc g1gc graal jfr jni-check jvmci jvmti management nmt parallelgc serialgc services vm-structs'
- OpenJDK target: OS: macosx, CPU architecture: x86, address length: 64
- Version string: 11.0.16-internal+0-adhoc.sadman.jdk11u-dev-master (11.0.16-internal)

Tools summary:

- Boot JDK:       openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)  (at /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home)
- Toolchain:      clang (clang/LLVM from Xcode 13.4)
- C Compiler:     Version 13.1.6 (at /usr/bin/clang)
- C++ Compiler:   Version 13.1.6 (at /usr/bin/clang++)

Build performance summary:

- Cores to use:   12
- Memory limit:   16384 MB

And it remind me that

jdk11u-dev-master/src/hotspot/share/jfr/periodic/jfrNetworkUtilization.cpp:59:30: error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
assert(interfaces != NULL, "invariant");

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/assert.h:98:9: note: macro 'assert' defined here
#define assert(e) \

Which means the source codes of jdk use two arguments assert, but my Mac just support one argument assert.

Answer (score 0):

In `./test/hotspot/gtest/unittest.hpp` in the jdk11u source there is this comment and redefinition of `assert`:

```
// gtest/gtest.h includes assert.h which will define the assert macro, but hotspot has its
// own standards incompatible assert macro that takes two parameters.
// The workaround is to undef assert and then re-define it. The re-definition
// must unfortunately be copied since debug.hpp might already have been
// included and a second include wouldn't work due to the header guards in debug.hpp.
#ifdef assert
  #undef assert
  #ifdef vmassert
    #define assert(p, ...) vmassert(p, __VA_ARGS__)
  #endif
#endif
```

Somehow this has been broken for `test/hotspot/gtest/jfr/test_networkUtilization.cpp`... it appears to be that `assert` is getting redefined in one of the includes *after* `unittest.hpp`.

You can fix the compile by moving the `#include` of `unittest.hpp` down a bit, see this diff:

```
--- a/test/hotspot/gtest/jfr/test_networkUtilization.cpp
+++ b/test/hotspot/gtest/jfr/test_networkUtilization.cpp
@@ -42,12 +42,12 @@
 #include "utilities/globalDefinitions.hpp"
 #include "utilities/growableArray.hpp"
 
-#include "unittest.hpp"
-
 #include <vector>
 #include <list>
 #include <map>
 
+#include "unittest.hpp"
+
 namespace {
 
   class MockFastUnorderedElapsedCounterSource : public ::FastUnorderedElapsedCounterSource {
```

Answer (score -1):

compiling openjdk11 on macos monterey is succe

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: could you give me some advice about my problem